# Why didn't Allah created us in jannah without test?

Tags: allah, jannah, creation

Allah can do anything without the slightest of effort. As well as Allah giving us "free will", why didn't He create all of the mankind and all of the heavens and the earth in Jannah without any kind of test?

For instance, if my dad was born with super power that makes him able to do anything he wishes to, my dad will give me so much knowledge that I wouldn't need to go to school. Then he'll give so much money that I wouldn't need to rely to anyone as well as beautiful wife, happy family, etc.

Not only the mankind, He could have given free will and Jannah to his angels, mountains, heaven, earth, animals, trees, etc. not to mention, that they're more loyal than humans as they praise Allah nonstop, which makes them almost more deserving than human.

Why then didn't He? What reason was there for giving humans in particular both free will and this test?

Comment: It was his plan. He did not told us why he did not made certain decisions..

Comment: What you suggested means that Allah should've never created this world! While Allah should manifest and exhaust His full creative will which entails creating us down in this lowest plane!

Comment: I think its about understanding the value through earning. While earning, you would also understand the price.

Comment: Just my opinion: So that people cannot complain about why someone got more and some got the highest ranks while others are in the lower ranks etc.

Answer (score -1):

**It is the sign of His supremacy, That he did what he want.**

> (Allah) Most Gracious! (1)
>
> It is He Who has taught the Qur'an. (2)
>
> He has created man: (3)
>
> He has taught him speech (and intelligence). (4)
>
> The sun and the moon follow courses (exactly) computed; (5)
>
> And the herbs and the trees - both (alike) prostrate in adoration. (6)
>
> And the Firmament has He raised high, and He has set up the Balance
>   (of Justice), (7)
>
> In order that ye may not transgress (due) balance. (8)
>
> So establish weight with justice and fall not short in the balance.
>   (9)
>
> It is He Who has spread out the earth for (His) creatures: (10)
>
> Therein is fruit and date-palms, producing spathes (enclosing dates);
>   (11)
>
> Also corn, with (its) leaves and stalk for fodder, and sweet-smelling
>   plants. (12)
>
> Then which of the favours of your Lord will ye deny? (13)
>
> Noble Quraan : 55 Ar-Rahman

**And it is the proof of His Mercy, that he gives us chance to purify ourself**.

> Ha'. Mim. (1)
>
> By the Clear Book; (2)
>
> verily We have made it an Arabic Qur'an that you may understand. (3)
>
> Indeed it is transcribed in the Original Book with Us; sublime and
>   full of wisdom. (4)
>
> Should We divert this Good Counsel from you because you are a people
>   immersed in extravagance? (5)
>
> How many a Prophet did We send to the earlier peoples! (6)
>
> Yet never did a Prophet come to them but they mocked him. (7)
>
> We utterly destroyed them although they were greater in might than
>   these. The examples of ancient peoples have gone before. (8)
>
> Yet if you were to ask them: “Who created the heavens and the earth?”
>   they will certainly say: “The All-Mighty, the All-Knowing has created
>   them.” (9)
>
> He it is Who made this earth for you a cradle and made in it pathways
>   for you that you may find the way to your destination; (10)
>
> Noble Quraan : 43 Az-Zukhruf

Allah decide what to happen and where to happen. No one have power to question We have to be thankful to Allah, our Lord, Most Merciful for what he gives us.

> By the sun and its heat and brightness, (1)
>
> and by the moon as it follows it; (2)
>
> and by the day as it displays the sun's glory, (3)
>
> and by the night as it envelopes the sun; (4)
>
> and by the sky and by Him Who made it; (5)
>
> and by the earth and by Him Who stretched it out; (6)
>
> and by the soul and by Him Who perfectly proportioned it, (7)
>
> and imbued it with (the consciousness of) its evil and its piety: (8)
>
> He who purifies it will prosper, (9)
>
> and he who suppresses it will be ruined. (10)
>
> In their presumptuous insolence the Thamud called the Truth a lie (11)
>
> when their arch-criminal rose up in rage. (12)
>
> Then Allah's Messenger warned them: “Hands off the she-camel and her
>   drink!” (13)
>
> But they rejected his statement as a lie and hamstrung the she-camel.
>   For that crime their Lord rumbled down upon them, utterly razing them
>   to the ground. (14)
>
> He has no fear of its sequel. (15)
>
> Noble Quraan: 91 As Shams

**Follow Allah and his Messenger and do righteous deeds. In sha Allah, you will find yourself. Don't be depressed about yourself and don't be arrogant about yourself. Be Thankful to Allah for whatever he gives to you.**

> By the time, (1)
>
> Verily man is in loss, (2)
>
> But not those who themselves believe and work righteous works, and
>   enjoin upon each other the truth, and enjoin upon each other
>   endurance. (3)
>
> Noble Quraan :103 Al-Asr

**Yes! There is all answers, in the Book of Allah, The Noble Quraan. It is a guidance for those who seek.**

> Alif. Lam Mim (1)
>
> This Book whereof there is no doubt, is a guidance unto the
>   God-fearing. (2)
>
> Who believe in the Unseen, and establish prayer, and out of that
>   wherewith We have provided them expend. (3)
>
> And who believe in that which hath been sent down unto thee and that
>   which hath been sent down before thee and of the Hereafter they are
>   convinced. (4)
>
> These are on guidance from their Lord, and these they are the blissful
>   ones. (5)
>
> Noble Quraan : 2 Al-Baqarah

Answer (score -1):

Peace be upon you,

Allah created Adam (A.S) to live in Paradise but there was a tree from which Allah prohibited him (A.S) to eat. You see that what I have mentioned in Surah Al-Baqarah Ayat No. 35. But Adam did not obeyed Allah because of Satan. And thus Allah sent Adam (A.S) to The Earth.
If Adam had obeyed Allah to not eat from that tree ever, now we were be the dwellers of Paradise.
Therefore, Allah sends every human to test him, whether he obeys Me or Satan. So, whoever obeys Allah, his abode will be Paradise.

Comment: But why was that tree there in the first place? _That_ is the question. Why was there a condition on staying in paradise? Seems like an awfully cruel thing to do, especially if you are omniscient and know that mankind will be tempted and is likely to fail.

Answer (score -1):

Because not everyone would go to heaven. Some would have to go to hell but then God would be sending people to hell without them doing anything. How would you feel if you were brought to the judge and before you saying anything then just say execute this person?!

And since God is the fairest judge ever he allows his servants to come and sin...only after they show their true face...God will send them to hell and others to heaven.

Comment: _"Because not everyone would go to heaven. Some would have to go to hell"_ Why? This doesn't make any sense. Why is there a need for hell? Why do some _have_ to go there?

Comment: @TheRavenQueen you should also be asking the same question for heaven. But to answer your question: see [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/41516/16719). There are some folks who no matter what you do, they don't want to worship/obey God. Their **niyya** is to always disobey him. If they are sent to hell for 100000years and then come back to earth for a second chance...they would still disobey him (kill, rape, steal, deceive, etc). Having that said there are many many who will get cleansed in the afterlife...because they were sinful believers, they did wrong but felt ashamed.

Comment: Those who won't ever become cleansed are people who don't feel ashamed anymore.

Comment: That's not an answer. a) Just because you don't believe doesn't mean you'll murder or rape, you already disobey by not believing no matter how good of a person you are. b) None of this needs to exist! We are talking about the premise that there is no need for earth to exist like this. Just eternal paradise without anything before or after. No one even could disobey because everyone is purified, all 'bad' desires are eliminated. (At least that's the idea I got from answers on this site.) Why is a test necessary?

Comment: @TheRavenQueen this would be my last comment: The question is why did allah create jannah without a test I said it's because since God is fair and kind he let's us give it a try—even though he knows. Then *you* went on a tangent question of "Why is there a need for hell" I answered because they have an **eternal intention of sinning**. To answer your last comment: "Why is a test necessary" It's NOT necessary...the test exists because God is kind and fair, see my answer to the original question. I hope this answers your questions...if you have any more questions you can open a chat room

Comment: [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57390/why-is-there-a-test) is the room

Answer (score -2):

Salaam

Suppose you addressed this complaint to Allah, saying that you lacked a certain specific power; and that you considered this lack as an evil.

And suppose He in his beneficent mercy granted you this power.

Then a while later, men being men - you or someone else decided that there was another power that you lacked; and again you beseeched Allah to grant you this power; and again in His beneficent mercy granted you this power...

You can see where this is going - eventually you or someone else will ask to be coequal with Allah; but no-one can be coequal with Allah...

Comment: i down voted because you missed main question to answer: "Why didn't Allah created us in jannah without test?"

Comment: @nim: the question hardly mention the world as testing ground in the body of your question; rather why his dad *hasn't got* super-powers, or why angels or trees *don't have* free-will - which is why I mentioned *lack* - ie something missing.

Comment: What you could pick me up on instead is that the answer isn't referenced and therefore without scholarly backing ...

Comment: But then again neither is the question.

Comment: _"men being men - you or someone else decided that there was another power that you lacked"_ But Allah was the one making "men being men" in the sense of craving more power a thing in the first place. He could have just created men who are eternally happy with what they are given, right? How is Jannah supposed to work otherwise if he's not able to make someone eternally happy?